# Feasibility of plywood for fence panels

Tags: waterproofing, plywood

I have a 4' high chain link fence that I want to block the view of the neighbor's yard.  Slats would be cheap, but only offer 80% coverage.  Looking for a cheap solution, would PT plywood work?  Would painting it with a polyurathane varnish be enough?  Here is an idea of what I want to do:

[image: Sample Panels]

I plan on smaller pieces in length than shown, but want something quick and easy.

Comment: A 4' high fence doesn't really block the view. Plywood is non-standard and would not give a good appearance on either side. It would have to be painted frequently. If the sight of the neighbor's yard is objectionable to you, then a 6' tall "privacy fence" is really what is needed.

Comment: Rather than fight the "drunk welder" style of that fence, I'd just stay on that page and go with a ["dazzle" scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dazzle_camouflage).  In that case plywood would be exactly the right stuff.

Comment: What does "would it work" mean to in this case? Be enough for what? Your question is unclear. In any case, I agree with Jim, and I LOLed out loud at Harper's creative idea.

Comment: Would it work mean would it be waterproof.  But yeah, "drunk welder' style does strangely describe it!